# What is it called when an arguer blames an action upon subconscious thoughts?

Tags: phrase-requests

**What is it called when Person A asserts that Person B performed an action due to Person B's subconscious thoughts?** That is, what is it called  the accuser assumes the modus operandi of the accused.

#### Contextual Examples

1. Jane Doe misses an interview for a CSR position John Doe networked her to. John Doe asserts that she forgot about it because "She didn't really want it'.
2. When a rapist or sexual assaulter claims their victim 'wanted it'.

Additionally, is there a fallacy associated with that type of (faulty) deduction?

Edit: Clarified the assumption being made by the arguer.

Comment: I think you could describe this as *projection.*

Comment: Armchair psychologizing

Comment: @aparente001 with your permission i will answer with such.

Comment: tricky ... it's not the guilty party but the accusers thinking.  More research.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify who's motus operandi is being assumed (the accused).

Comment: @KareemElashmawy - I think maybe you mean "internal thought process" rather than "modus operandi."

Comment: In example 1, I think Jane could respond to John: "Please don't psychoanalyze me."  If you want a narrator description of what John did: John was speculating as to Jane's subconscious thought processes.  Kareem, for a well posed question here, you're supposed to include a sentence showing how you'd like to use the word or phrase you're seeking.

Answer (score 1):

**victim blaming**  [TFD](https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Victim+blaming) wiki encyclopedia

> Victim blaming occurs when the victim of a crime or any wrongful act
>   is held entirely or partially responsible for the harm that befell
>   them.

Read the pros and cons of **victimology.**

Apparently coined by William Ryan, the phrase "blaming the victim" in his 1971 book Blaming the Victim (same link)

And here is the complexity: (again same link)

> The common behavior of the aggressor seeing themselves as more of the
>   "victim" than the abused, justifying a horrific act by way of their
>   "moral complexity". This usually stems from an "excessive sensitivity"
>   to insults, which he finds as a consistent pattern in abusive
>   husbands. Essentially, the abuse the perpetrator administers is
>   generally excessive, in comparison to the act/acts that they claim as
>   to have provoked them.

And because of the complexity it appears to me that some [projection](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/projection) is in play too.

Comment: I do see your point; but, wouldn't this be assuming what the accuser is subconsciously thinking  rather than the accused?

Comment: one more edit ...

Comment: @KareemElashmawy  am i close to what you are after?

Answer (score 1):

psychologise

> to speculate in psychological terms or on psychological motivations
>   
>  to explain or interpret in psychological terms
>   [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/psychologize)
>
> to make interpretations of behaviour and mental processes 
>   [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/psychologize)
>
> v.tr.
>  To explain or analyze (behavior, for example) in
>   psychological terms.
>  [The American Heritage® Medical
>   Dictionary](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/psychologize)

The fallacy is begging the question.

> beg the question
>   1. To assume to be true what one is purporting to prove in an argument.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Begging+the+question)
>
> More specifically
>  To beg the question is to assume the truth of
>   the conclusion of an argument in the premises in order for the
>   conclusion to follow.
>  [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question)

```
Left-handed people are better painters because...
right-handed people can't paint as well. 
|^^^^^^^^^^^assumed premise^^^^^^^^^^^^|
```

1. Jane Doe missed her interview
2. If someone misses her interview it means they subconsciously don't want the job - This premise is assumed but not self-evident or proved.
3. Jane Doe doesn't want the job - Conclusion based on accepting the dubious second premise (begging the question).

Your rape example may be more like the first example, or it may have an unknown premise in the mind of the perpetrator (ie., "She really wants me"), which may be be simply assumed without proof or indication.